# Can you identify me?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You know who I am?

If you cannot identify me, use the following pictures:

[image]

I am not in an order.

Hint:

> You might not know who I am until you visited this puzzle.

Comment: Iced strawberry cake?

Comment: That's actually raspberry.

Comment: Is that chicken on the plate?

Comment: yes..it is.....

Comment: Okk... Bridge and Cash might refer to a game of bridge.

Comment: Yes, I can identify you, you're Sathi Reddy, and indeed I did not know who you were before visiting this puzzle. More seriously, though, all images include something flat, a surface of some kind - their pier, the monetary notes, the layers of the raspberry cake and the plate. There must be some connection there.

Comment: Are those chicken wings or chicken balls?  I can't really tell.

Comment: Chicken 65 is amazing!!

Comment: Sweet and Spice

Comment: does the answer point to your professional background ?

Comment: @WeShall no, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer and I think you're a

> Stack Exchange Friend!

The answers already given for the second and third pictures give us

> Stack Exchange

The first picture is

> The **end** of a bridge or dock or something

The last picture is

> **Fri**ed chicken legs

So we put them together to get

> Stack Exchange Friend

This answer also explains the hint:

> "You might not know who I am until you visited this puzzle" because we might not know you (a stack exchange friend) until we saw your puzzle!

Comment: You tried well,but need extra exercise to get the answer...I am not a legend!

Comment: I was close before but I think I got it now!

Comment: Fourth picture indicates "Fry" and first picture indicates "end", so fry+end = friend. I am your stack exchange friend.

Comment: congrats!!! you got it. You have won by bounty too..

Answer (score 17):

Reverse Google-image-searching each picture, from top left, clockwise gives you

> 1. Bahia Key Rail Bridge (from the Florida Keys)
>  2. Consumer economics
>  3. Chicken leg fry kerala style
>  4. Full stack

From this, plus the hint, we definitely see that part of the answer will be

> **Stack Exchange** (pictures 4 then 2)

This is supported by the

> edit history, where (instead of the current "exchange" picture) there used to be a picture of a water glass overflowing, so OP switched from **Stack Overflow** to **Stack Exchange**.

I suppose, also, that a liberal interpretation of the first picture could yield

> **Puzzling**, since a bridge that ends abruptly is indeed puzzling, though of course there are many many other words that picture could represent.

And in the category of rampant and ridiculous speculation,

> The bottom-right picture could be **Meta** if you look at it as "mixed meat".

Comment: While 'm\*t\*' is indeed 'm\*\*t' mixed, that image is definitely not 'mixed m\*\*t', so that's an odd link. That said, this is otherwise a very convincing answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, you may have noticed there were some serious rationalization gymnastics to get that to work!

Comment: @Dan Russell, you are great..but the answer is quite different than that..check the hint.

Comment: Related to the first image, but probably coincidental: the main chat room for the gaming stack exchange (Arqade) is called The Bridge.

Answer (score 8):

If images use this scheme:

> 1 2 
>   
>  3 4

I can read (with a bit of imagination):

> 1 = **bridge**
>
> 2 = cash => **cache**
>
> 3 = a cake with raspberry? A Raspberry Pie or... [**Raspberry PI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) 
>
> 4 = a plate with something... it doesn't matter. It is a **plate**.

So,

> since these are all electronic references, the mysterious object is an electronic thing with a small computer (CPU + cache), a plate for building my project and bridges (connections) for I/O (input and output). So it is a [**GPIO integrated circuit**](http://www.andremiller.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/arduino_rpi_serial_hardware.jpg).

Yes, maybe I answered with too much imagination!

Comment: the question states "who" instead of "what"

Comment: @lois6b yes I know. But I often see riddles written as the "misterious thing" is personificated, speaks and ask "Who am I" (being an animal or an object). As I have written, I tried with a lot of imagination!

Comment: well, thats true hahaha  your reasoning is similar to mine, but im not sure yet

Comment: @Iois6b is correct... who am I?

Comment: @marcoresk.. well tried..But it is not the answer..

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> Johnny Cash

Because

> Cash is in his name, he has done a song called "bridge over troubled waters" and "chicken in black" He also is likes raspberry cake very much as in this photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CHkB.jpg

Its a long shot, but worth it :)

Comment: not that long! seems legit. The photo before the money one, was a glass with troubled water

Comment: What do you mean a glass with troubled water?

Comment: if you see the edits, OP posted another photo before the one with the money. and that photo was a glass with troubled water http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfzLA.jpg

Comment: but note that the money seem to be buying lotto

Comment: AH, got you. Thanks! I am possibly wrong then ;)

Comment: i believe in you <3

Comment: I will keep thinking!

Answer (score 2):

> Stack Exchange Spicy Kerala Chicken (Bahia Honda Rail Bridge) of course

Comment: I agree with the first two words of this approach relating to the second and third picture.  Is the first picture a pier? (Pierre?)

Comment: @Keeta No. It's not a pier. It's the BHRB identified in the spoiler

Comment: @Strawberry.. you tried well...please use hint....

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely you! Because, you should be a human being!

So, again, it's you:

> [Sathi Reddy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29090/sathi-reddy)

Actually I did not know you before I visited this puzzle. Regular community members know you. That's why you used **might**!

#### Sorry:

I did not see the [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42623/can-you-identify-me#comment127516_42623) of [einpoklum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25116/einpoklum). I have seen it now and he gave this answer 7 hours ago!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why, based on the puzzle, do you think this is the answer? Answers should give full explanation of their reasoning.

Comment: @Deusovi sorry? what else should I explain?

Answer (score 1):

The top left image, while being the

> Bahai Honda Rail Bridge, is in the Florida Keys. I think that this might be referencing the word Key

The bottom left and top right images

> Are Stack and Exchange respectively

Whereas the bottom right image

> Looks like a very spicy, or hot meal.

Making the final phrase potentially

> Key to Stack Exchange Heat, referring to Hot Network Questions.

After all, this question was

> In the Hot Network questions for a while, so perhaps the OP knew what he was talking about :), Fun images, high views, many answers.